# Asymptotics for number of $p$-regular partitions of $n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, partitions, modular-representation-theory

The number of simple modules $D^{\lambda}=S^{\lambda}/S^{\lambda}\cap (S^{\lambda})^{\bot}$ of the symmetric group over a field $k$ such that $\text{char}(k)=p > 0$ is the number of $p$-regular partitions of $n$, $|\mathcal{P}_{p,n}|$.

What are asymptotics for this?

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comments, the fact that $|\mathcal{P}_{p,n}|$ is the number of conjugacy classes of $S_n$ with order prime to $p$ requires a proof, which is Proposition 3 of [this paper of Chan](https://math.mit.edu/%7Echarchan/ModularRepresentationsSymmetricGroupSeminar.pdf). She uses a generating function approach where $\Pi_{i \nmid p, i \ge 0} \left(1+x^i+x^{2i}+\ldots \right)$ has $n^{th}$ coefficient equal to $|\mathcal{P}_{p,n}|$.

Comment: if there exists a purely combinatorial definition of $p$-regular partitions, it could be useful to include it in the question

Comment: A $p$-regular partition is one in which no part is repeated $p$ or more times. The fact that the number of $p$-regular partitions of $n$ is also the number of conjugacy classes of $S_{n}$ consisting of elements of order prime to $p$ ( ie the number of partitions with no part divisible by $p$) requires an argument, but is well-known ( to those who know it!).

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Right, thank you. Chan gives a nice description of $p$-regular partitions and a proof of that fact in Proposition 3 in the now linked paper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is answered in the paper of Peter Hagis, "Partitions with a restriction on the multiplicities of the summands" Trans AMS 155 (1971), 375-384. Corollary 4.2 at the end of the paper is probably the simplest estimate to understand.